# How to import LESS file, but not render it?

Tags: less, dotless

I have a `.less` file where I keep all my global variables. For example:

**lib.less**

```
@primary-color: red;

.primary-font{
  font-family:Arial;
}
```

On one of my pages I have a page-specific CSS file. For example:

**Homepage.less**
@import "lib.less";

```
.Login
{
   color:@primary-color;
   .primary-font;
}
```

I preprocess LESS using [dotless](http://www.dotlesscss.org/). This renders "Homepage.less" to the client as:

```
.primary-font{
  font-family:Arial;
}

.Login
{
   color:red;
   font-family:Arial;
}
```

I don't want `.primary-font` to be rendered as I'm only using this as a style collection for importing into other classes. The output I really want is:

```
.Login
{
   color:red;
   font-family:Arial;
}
```

Is there any way of importing styles from another `.less` file for use in other classes, without them being rendered to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with MVC, this is something you have to do in the LESS itself. See: http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-not-outputting-the-mixin

Essentially, if you don't want the mixin output as a class, you just need to suffix it with parenthesis:

```
.primary-font() {
    font-family: Arial;
}
```